# Mac Boot Camp Assistant - how to always show operation system selection when restarting?

Tags: macos, bootcamp

I don't want to have a default one - I want the option to choose which one I want each time I restart my Mac without having to press the Option Key.

Is it possible? and how?

Comment: Install and configure rEFInd.